# .isproj cannot be opened because of its project type (.isproj) is not supported

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I've got 2 VS 2008 based solutions I'm opening up and both have projects that are .NET 3.5.  But when I open both solutions in VS 2008, both have some .isproj file(s) and I get this stupid error right after I open the solution:

c:....\somefilename.isproj cannot be opened because its project type (.isproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

When I open the .isproj I see that the project version appears to be VS 2008:

9.0.30729

So I do not understand why I'd still be getting this error and I have never even seen or at least had an error with a file of extension .isproj in any of my apps before.  I guess it is used for MS Build?

Comment: Not all project types are supported by Visual Studio out of the box (or depending on which options are selected during installation). At a guess, are these `.isproj` files related to InstallShield? Or can you think of another product that you use that has the initials `is`? I don't recognise the extension myself.

Comment: Not sure, just checked out this web poject and another WCF project (both under seperate .sln).  And they both have this filetype for yes, a setup folder that's inside the solution for some kind of setup of the web services, etc.

Answer (score 15):

.isproj is for "InstallShield MSBuild Project File" and to use it, you would need to buy proper tools (more info here https://www.flexerasoftware.com/install/products/installshield)

Comment: There is a free version for Visual Studio users at http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio

Comment: Peter's link is to InstallShield Limited Edition - this version is limited to Visual Studio 2010 to 2015, and the supported editions are not free - Professional, Premium, Enterprise and Ultimate. Having said that, it solved my problem of opening old projects with .isproj files!